# How to execute a Angular controller method when I have its name as a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS controller I have an event handler which receives an argument. The argument has a method name as string, which I need to execute. How do I call the method in my controller?

I have seen this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) but it doesn't work for me on the controller. Here is my code

The event is created by a directive which is a confirmation dialog. Event fires when the user clicks Yes.

```
app.directive('yesNoModal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        yesNoData: '=',
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.handleYes = function() {
            $scope.$emit('clickedYes', { "yesNoData": $scope.yesNoData  });
        }
        $scope.handleNo = function() {
            $scope.$emit('clickedNo');
        }
    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/templates/yes-no-modal.html',
  }
})
```

Event handler

```
$scope.$on('clickedYes', function(event, arg) {
    console.log(arg)
    window[arg.yesNoData.yesMethod]()
});
```

`window[arg.yesNoData.yesMethod]` returns `undefined` in my case. I also tried with `$window` but I get undefined for the same. The function with the name  of value of `arg.yesNoData.yesMethod` variable is defined in the controller as a method and the value of `yesNoData` is set before the modal is loaded. On clicking Yes in the modal the event is handled

```
function deleteRequirement() {
    console.log("In delete requirement")
}
```

Comment: You can pass the function reference to your event handler and that way not bother about this.

Comment: If it's the name of a method of some object (such as a scope) you need to access it through that object not through window. But best to do as @Burimi says and just pass a function around rather than a string.

Comment: The function was not defined within the scope, so I thought I could call it. I moved it to the $scope and implemented Anubhav's solution. Thanks You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$scope[arg.yesNoData.yesMethod]()` instead of `window[arg.yesNoData.yesMethod]()` since it is a method inside the `$scope` object and not the `window` object

Comment: Implemented it after moving the `deleteRequirement` function to $scope. TY